# Trying to change background color in chart js filter

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am new to development and trying to do a project where I creating a webpage which have price range filter and there is a chart linked to that price range filter. What I am trying to do is change the background color of my labels of chartJs according to ranger filter. I want only labels in given range to show orange color and other labels should show light pink color, but here when I change background color after giving a condition all the labels' color get changed but i want only labels falling under filter range change the color.

[trying to achieve range filter in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0EOA.png)

```js
 let canvasElement = document.getElementById("productChart");

 const dataPoints = [21, 0, 19, 3, 5, 0, 2, 3, 10, 4, 6, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 24, 30, 32, 45, 44, 22, 
 21, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0];


  const labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
  27, 28, 29, 30, 31]


 const backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.3)';

 const newBackgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 1)';

  let config = 
       {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            barPercentage: 0.5,
            barThickness: 5,
            maxBarThickness: 12,
            minBarLength: 2,
            // label: 'Number of Phones',
            data: dataPoints, //price
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 5,
            // borderSkipped: false,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    display: false, //this will remove only the label
                },
                grid: {
                   display:false,
                   borderColor: 'black',  // <-- this line is answer to initial question
                   borderWidth:2,
                  }    
                },
            y: {
                    display: false, //this will remove only the label 
            },  
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        
          tooltip: {   
           enabled: false,
           displayColors: false,
           padding: 10,
           yAlign: 'top',
            },
        },  
    }
}
 
 let productChart = new Chart(canvasElement, config)


 const start = document.getElementById('start')
 const end = document.getElementById('end')

function updateMin(range) {
   const minValue = labels.slice(range.value - 1, end.value);  
   let newLabels = productChart.config.data.labels
   for(let i = 0; i < newLabels.length; i++){
      value = newLabels[i];
      if (minValue.includes(value)){ 
        productChart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor=newBackgroundColor;
         }
   }  

 
   end.min = range.value
   productChart.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scriptable options for `backgroundColor` options. Based on the argument, context.index (see here the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options) you can decide at runtime which color to use.
In the below snippet, changing the stepper values, the chart will change the background colors.
I have used part of your code. Instead of using the stepper, you can use your slider or what you are using.

```js
const dataPoints = [21, 0, 19, 3, 5, 0, 2, 3, 10, 4, 6, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 24, 30, 32, 45, 44, 22, 
 21, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0];

const labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

const backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.3)';

const newBackgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 1)';  

const from = document.getElementById("from");
const to = document.getElementById("to");

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
      //barPercentage: 0.5,
      //barThickness: 5,
      //maxBarThickness: 12,
      //minBarLength: 2,
      data: dataPoints,
      backgroundColor(ctx) {
        const fromValue = parseFloat(from.value);
        const toValue = parseFloat(to.value);
        const value = ctx.index + 1;
        if (value >= fromValue && value <= toValue) {
          return newBackgroundColor;
        }
        return backgroundColor;
      },
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.2)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: 5,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        grid: {
          display:false,
        }    
      },
      y: {
        display: false, 
      },  
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {   
       enabled: false,
      },
    },  
  }
});
from.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myChart.update();
});
to.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myChart.update();
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
    From:
    <input type="number" id="from" min="1" max="31" value="1"/>
    To:
    <input type="number" id="to" min="1" max="31" value="31"/>
  </body>
</html>
```